Bottom bar innerpadding adds outside padding to the composable
When trying to prevent the overlaps that the bottom bar cause in the screen content in Jetpack Compose I have found this weird behaviour after adding the inner padding:

The code:
 Scaffold(
        topBar = {
            
        },
        bottomBar = {
          
        },
    ) { innerPadding->
        Box(
            modifier =
                Modifier.padding(innerPadding),
        ) {
            RootNavigationGraph(
                navController,
            )

Any idea? I dont know why is adding an extra padding above the composable

Try the below two codes, and see if either one works for you.
Scaffold(
topBar = { /* optional */ },
bottomBar = { /* Your bottom bar content */ },
) { innerPadding ->
    Box(
        modifier = Modifier.padding(bottom = innerPadding.calculateBottomPadding()),  // Only apply bottom padding
    ) {
        RootNavigationGraph(navController)
    }
}

or the below code,
Scaffold(
topBar = { /* optional */ },
bottomBar = { /* Your bottom bar content */ },
) { innerPadding ->
    Box(
        modifier = Modifier
            .padding(innerPadding)
            .consumeWindowInsets(innerPadding),  // Adjust for system insets if needed
    ) {
        RootNavigationGraph(navController)
    }
}


none of this changes do anything, still appearing
